# Define custom icons for global quick search

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

We are using mostly custom entities in our on-premise installation of Dynamics CRM 2016.

When using the global/quick search function, the search results show the generic entity icon even though custom icons have been configured and are also shown in the sitemap. The background of the custom icons has been taken from the solution but not the icon itself.

Can this be changed or is this functionality not available?

Comment: So your custom icon looks fine in the ribbon?

Comment: Yes, it does appear

Comment: And you've defined the 16x16 custom icon as well as the 32x32?

Comment: Yes, both. The smaller icon is IMO display in the solution explorer.

Comment: Give a shot at using an incognito / inprivate window, might be a browser cache issue

Comment: Does this mean that it is working for you when you just  add the icons for the entity in the solution? I checked: It is not a browser cache issue.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working for me. Here's a screenshot from our development environment. I've blocked out the Entity names, but you can see that the icons are different for each entity

```
CRM 365 Online
```

[image: Quick Search]

I think you may be affected by a cache issue as pointed out by others. All these entities (and their icons) have been in place for weeks.

Sorry it doesn't help you, but at least shows what the default behavior should be.

Comment: Weird. Our entities and icons have been in place for months. They worked. But not in global search. I don't believe in a cache issue after such a long time...